# How to find the smallest side of a triangle when the interior angles are unknown?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

I am confused on how to find the answer for this problem. So far what I believe would apply is the triangle inequality but I'm not sure on how to use it.

> The figure $ABC$ is a triangle so as $BDC$. It is known that the
>   length of $AB = 8$ inches and $\angle BAD = 2\,\angle BCD$ and
>   $\angle\,DBC = 3 \angle BCD$. Find the smallest whole number that $BD$
>   can attain.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&7\,\textrm{inches}\\
2.&4\,\textrm{inches}\\
3.&8\,\textrm{inches}\\
4.&5\,\textrm{inches}\\
5.&6\,\textrm{inches}\\
\end{array}$

So far the only thing I could come up with was to "guess" it might be $4$ since, $\angle BDA = 4\omega$ could it be that since $BD$ is opposing $2\omega$ hence that side might be $4$ inches. But that's how far I went. Needless to say that I'm unsure if that's a right way to go. Can somebody help me with this question?. Please try to include some drawing or sketch of the situation as I'd like to know what can I do to solve this problem relying mostly in geometry?.

Comment: BD=4 creates a degenerate triangle.

Comment: @Doug M Sorry but why would it cause it to be a degenerate triangle?. What do you mean?

Comment: @DougM I forgot some theoretical aspects of the triangular inequality but I think you were referring that when one side is equal to the sum of the other two will produce a straight line, hence no area and no triangle. Did you meant this?.

Comment: Consider the law of Sines.  $\frac {8}{\sin 4\omega} = \frac {4}{\sin 2\omega} \implies \frac {\sin 4\omega}{\sin 2\omega} = 2$ which is only true at the limit as $\omega$ approaches $0.$

Answer (score 2):

A possible path without trigonometry.

[image]

**EDIT** Added explicitely the angles in the diagram, as required in comments.

1. Draw line $BE$ so that $\angle EBC = \angle ACB $.
2. $\triangle EBC$ is isoceles (why?); $\triangle BDE$ is isosceles (why?); $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles (why?)

Now use triangular inequality on $\triangle BDE$, to get $2BD > 8$.

**EDIT** Since $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles, $\angle AEB \cong \angle EAB < 90°$, whereas one of the two between $\angle BDA$ and $\angle BDE$ is greater than or equal to $90°$. Since in any triangle the side opposite to the greater angle is greater, we can state either that $BD < BE$ or that $BD < AB$. So $BD< 8$.

**EDIT** (Thanks to [Lubin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17760/lubin) for pointing this out in comment)

Once the fact that $4<BD<8$ has been proven, one should also check whether an integer solution between $4$ and $8$ **does exist** for $BD$. I will try to show, then, that in fact $BD = 5$ is a valid solution. Consider the Figure below.

[image]

Start at point $D$ and draw a circle $\gamma_1$ centered in $D$ and with radius $5$; draw then a diameter of $\gamma_1$, and let $E$ be one of its endpoints. Draw a circle $\gamma_2$ centered in $E$ having radius $8$, which intersects $\gamma_1$ in $B$, and the line $DE$ (at the opposite side of $D$) in $C$. Finally draw circle $\gamma_3$ of radius $8$, centered in $B$. This intersects line $DE$ in two points. One is $E$; call the other one $A$. The triangle $\triangle ABC$ satisfies the requirements, with $BD = 5$, as desired.

Comment: Okay I found two of the isosceles triangles you mentioned, however I'm still stuck at how to use the triangular inequality on $\triangle BDE$. Because although $BE=8$ what's the value of $DE$?. Upon looking again I figured that $DE=BE$ since it is isoceles. But the thing is triangular inequality would be established as $BD+BD\leq 8$ then I searched in other sources and found that when one side is equal to the sum of the other two would yield a degenerate triangle, hence that would be $BD<4$ but stated this way I can't find a way to find the minimum other than zero or one?.

Comment: I might be lacking in understanding of triangle inequality or perhaps you did something I forgot to account for?. Can you help me with some theory or explain more what's happening?. Maybe you can include angles in the drawing because I struggled a bit to identify where were the isosceles you mentined.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell for triangular inequality $BD + DE \geq BE$ with equality only when the triangle degenerates. I will add some info on the angles as soon as I can, no problem.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell also is $BD \cong DE$, not $BE \cong DE$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell added angles in the Figure.

Comment: I like this better than my answer, but do you know that there is a case where $BD$ has length $5$? I think you ought to check that there even *is* an integral value for $BD$.

Comment: I also like your construction of a case where $BD=5$ ! Really nice.

Comment: @Lubin thanks for your feedback! I really appreciate.

Comment: @Matteo Sorry, I misunderstood the inequality, actually I found out before reading your comment, and it checks with what you meant. So as $BD+BD$ has to be greater than $8$ or in other words $8$ less than the sum of the other two. Is translated as $2BD>8$ hence $BD>4$ so the minimum integer that fits this inequality would be $5$ as you stated. For some reason I reversed the sign because when I read it in a rush I didn't noticed that.

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for adding the angles and the additional drawing of those circles. However I'm still confused at where did you get the inequality of $4<BD<8$?. The part where $BD>4$ comes from triangle inequality but where does it $BD<8$ comes from?.

Comment: @Lubin I made that post in a rush, yes I intended to say that $BD \cong DE$ since in computer keyboard $D$ is close to $E$ i incurred in that typo, sorry.

Comment: @Matteo Btw adding to the above question I'm curious, what software are you using to make those elegant drawings?. :)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell for $BD< 8$ consider using triangle inequality on $\triangle ABD$, for example (as a matter of fact I did not show this explicitly, being a direct consequence of the hypothesis; but I probably should have). I use Geogebra for the figures :)

Comment: @Matteo If I would use triangle inequality on $\triangle ABD$ what value do I set for $AD$?. As $AD+BD>8$. The only thing I can come up with is that $AD$ has to be greater than $0$ but where to go from there? it is not very explicit. Can you further help me on this?. Btw I'll give a try on geogebra so far I'm using Inkscape. ;)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell you're right. that does not work. I'll think a better solution. Now I got to take some sleep.. really late, here..

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell ok it was a little bit more subtle. Added an explaination on why $BD < 8$.

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for adding those explanations I think it was important to mention that one of the two sides of $\angle BDA$ and $\angle BDE$ is greater than or equal to $90^{\circ}$. But I think that what it was *missing* might had been that $AD < AB$ or $DE < BE$. As from what you mentioned regarding the sizes opposite to triangle's bigger angle. Is this correct?. I was also thinking that another way to prove $BD<8$ might come from using $\omega<30^{\circ}$ as mentioned by Lubin.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\angle ADB=4\omega$, Law of Sines tells you that the length of $BD$ is $\frac{8\sin(2\omega)}{\sin(4\omega)}$. Then, since $\sin(2\alpha)<2\sin\alpha$ for all acute angles $\alpha$, the fraction is always *greater* than $4$, whereas for $\omega=29^\circ$, $\angle ADB=116^\circ$, and Law of Sines gives the length of $BD$ to be about $7.54$in. This length clearly varies continuously with $\omega$ in the range $0<\omega<30^\circ$, so there are integer values for the length of $5,6,7$in. Your choice then is #4, $5$ inches.

Comment: I reached the part where you established $BD= \frac{8\sin 2\omega}{sin 4 \omega}$ But the rest is where I got stuck. I want to understand your answer but I don't know where the inequality $\sin 2\alpha < 2 \sin \alpha$ comes from?. If I use trigonometry simplification the only thing I could come up with was $\frac{4}{\cos 2\omega}=BD$. The angles \omega = 29^{\circ} and \angle ADB=116^{\circ} where do you got them? How can I get them too?. The range you given between $0<\omega<30^{\circ}$ where did you obtained?. I'd really hope you can explain to me these questions because I'm lost.

Comment: I’m sure you see, @ChrisSteinbeckBell, that $\angle ABD$ is $180^\circ-6\omega$. Since this has to be positive, $6\omega<180^\circ$. The inequality $\sin2\alpha<2\sin\alpha$ comes from the double-angle formula $\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$. I merely chose $29^\circ$ as an angle close to the “forbidden” angle $30^\circ$, because when $\omega=30^\circ$, you get a collapsed picture, where $BD$ coincides with $BA$, in other words, has length $8$in. I just wanted to get a good idea of the range of the function $\omega\mapsto$ length of $BD$.

Comment: @Lubin, Since you defenitely are much more expert than me, I would really appreciate if you could have a look at my edit and see if what I added could be considered a valid demonstration of the existence of a solution $\overline{BD} = 5$.

Comment: @Lubin. Thanks I understood how you obtained $180^{\circ} > \omega$. But the other part where you get the inequality is where I'm still confused. I know the double angle formula, the point where I don't understand is why $\sin 2 \alpha$ has to be *lesser than* $2 \sin\alpha$?. I mean double angle is an equality **how** is it transformed into an inequality?. I want to understand this part. Is there anything in the picture that leads me to this statement?.

Comment: @Lubin I believe that the result of $\textrm{7.54 in}$ comes from inserting $\omega=29^{\circ}$ in the law of sines. To which it [does in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8*+(sin+(2*29))%2F(sin(4*29))) I'd like to compliment your answer as you did to Matteo's because its a more analytic one.

Comment: To your question about $\sin2\alpha<2\sin\alpha$, you use the double-angle formula I quoted, and the fact that $\cos\alpha<1$.

Comment: @Lubin I'm so sorry. I totally overlooked that fact from cosine function. By the way I voice my opinion that the last comment about the cosine function along the previous one regarding $180-6\omega>0$ should be upgraded and added to your answer because they do explain better the reason why you chosen those decision in particular.! Anyway thanks this along Matteo's answer did helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Drawing Issocoles Triangles was inspired and leads to an easy analysis

$\angle ADB = 4\omega$ as its external to Triangle $BED$

$BD$ at max lies along $AD$ when $\angle ADB =120°$

$BD$ min when $\angle ADB = 90°$

$2\omega = 45° \text{ & } AD = BD\\
8^2 = 2BD^2\\
\therefore BD = 4 \sqrt 2 ≈ 5.656$

$BD$ again nearly reaches max just before triangle collapses when $AD \implies 16 \text{ and } \angle ADB \implies 0°$

Smallest whole number is $6$